# Neglect a function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

When I click mainDiv, the function `mainDiv()` will be invoked,
when I click subDiv, both `mainDiv()` and `subDiv()` functions are invoked.

I want to invoke only the `subDiv()` function when I click subDiv. How can I achieve this?

**CODE:**

```
<div onclick="mainDiv()">
  show main div
  <div onclick="subDiv()">
    show sub div
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function  mainDiv(){
    alert("main div is clicked");
  }
  function  subDiv(){
    alert("sub div is clicked");
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `e.stopPropogation()`

**HTML**

```
<div onclick="subDiv(event)">  //<--- pass event parameter
```

**javascrip**

```
function  subDiv(e){    

   if(e.stopPropagation){  // check stoppropogation is avilable
      e.stopPropagation();  //use stopPropogation
   }else{
      e.cancelBubble = true;  // for ie8 and below
   }
   alert("sub div is clicked");
}
```

Comment: stopPropagation isn't available in IE8.

Comment: I did not tested in IE8,In other browsers are working will,I hope same will be happen in case of IE8,thank you :)

Comment: no worries... it will... anyways thanks... gald that it helped... happy coding.. :)

Answer (score 3):

You might use [stopPropagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event.stopPropagation) in all browsers except IE8 (and older ones from the same company). But if you want to be compatible, you should use the solution [described in quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html) :

```
   <div onclick="subDiv(event)">

   function  subDiv(e){
     e.cancelBubble = true;
     if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();
     alert("sub div is clicked");
   }
```

**[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/ijidok/1/edit)**

Comment: With inline events he won't have the event object available as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function mainDiv() {
    alert("main div is clicked");
}
function subDiv(e) {
    if (!e)
        e = window.event;

    //IE9 & Other Browsers
    if (e.stopPropagation) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
    //IE8 and Lower
    else {
        e.cancelBubble = true;
    }
    alert("sub div is clicked");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    <div onclick="mainDiv()">
      show main div
      <div onclick="subDiv(event);">
        show sub div
      </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function  mainDiv(){
        alert("main div is clicked");
      }
      function  subDiv(arg){
        arg.stopPropagation();
        alert("sub div is clicked" + arg);

      }
</script>
```

To support IE 8 and lower use arg.cancelBubble

Comment: stopPropagation isn't available in IE8.

Comment: use cancelBubble() for ie8 and lower